# Posting on user's timeline on the behalf of the user

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I created and APP on the Facebook.

Now I am trying to post a comment on the user's timeline using the Graph API but I cannot undestand what I need to do.

I already authorized the Application (I authorized this permissions: **'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,email'**).

If I look on my profile -> privacy I can see that the APP can:

```
This app can: Post on your behalf
This app may post on your behalf, including status updates, photos and more.

Last data access:   
Basic InformationToday
See details · Learn more
Posts on your behalf:   
Who can see posts this app makes for you on your Facebook timeline? 
Public
Notifications:  
When to notify you? 
The app sends you a notification
```

So this part seems OK.

On my application I do the following to try to post somenthing on my timeline (I need to post it when I am off line).

1) GET : **https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=*APPID*&client_secret=*APP_SECRET*&grant_type=client_credentials**

RESPONSE:

```
access_token = 422828347771671|UdQELQIf0N7krF4JUo7VwtPLTkk
```

2) GET: **https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=*myemail*&type=user**

RESPONSE:

```
_"error":_{
______"message":_"A_user_access_token_is_required_to_request_this_resource_",
______"type":_"OAuthException",
______"code":_102
___}
```

But reading the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching) it seems that this request does not need any kind of access token.

I also tried to add the access token, but the result is still the same.

3) I know my facebookid so I tried to use it directly:

POST: **https://graph.facebook.com/100001139132403/feed**

ARGUMENT:

access_token=422828347771671|UdQELQIf0N7krF4JUo7VwtPLTkk,

message=Hello

RESPONSE:

```
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) This API call requires a valid app_id.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

So I tried to add **client_id=APPID** and **app_id=APPID**, I tried to put one, the other and also both arguments as GET or POST but nothing changed.

I checked the APPId ad it is correct.

Do someone have any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cant simply generate a user access_token by querying to a URL. What you did gives the App access token and as the error say, you are trying to do something, that needs user access_token.

**Refer and implement this : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/server-side-login/**

And use that access_token for the rest of the processes.